# How to groupby every n rows and sum but keep original structure in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list(range(1,10)), list(range(11,20)))), columns=['a', 'b'])
print(d)



  a   b
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  4  14
4  5  15
5  6  16
6  7  17
7  8  18
8  9  19
```

I want to groupby every 3 rows in column b and get the sum. However, I don't want to collapse the df to the groupby index. I want to keep the original a column, but I want to replace the b column with that sum value of the group that row falls into, like this:

```
d_ = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list(range(1,10)), [36, 36, 36, 45, 45, 45, 54, 54, 54])), columns=['a', 'b'])
print(d_)


   a   b
0  1  36
1  2  36
2  3  36
3  4  45
4  5  45
5  6  45
6  7  54
7  8  54
8  9  54
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d=d.assign(b=d.groupby(d.index//3)['b'].transform('sum'))



  a   b
0  1  36
1  2  36
2  3  36
3  4  45
4  5  45
5  6  45
6  7  54
7  8  54
8  9  54
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform` like

```
In [5]: d.groupby(d.index // 3).transform('sum')
Out[5]: 
    a   b
0   6  36
1   6  36
2   6  36
3  15  45
4  15  45
5  15  45
6  24  54
7  24  54
8  24  54
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(d.groupby((d['a']-1)//3)
    .apply(lambda df: df.assign(b=df['b'].sum()))
    .reset_index(drop = True)
    )
```

produces

```
    a   b
0   1   36
1   2   36
2   3   36
3   4   45
4   5   45
5   6   45
6   7   54
7   8   54
8   9   54
```

here we `groupby` by the 3s (the `by` list looks like `[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,...]`), and then we apply the function `.assign(b=df['b'].sum())`to each subgroup which replaces 'b' column with the sum of of 'b' values in tha tsubgroup

Answer (score 1):

If the index is a simple range, you can group in multiples of three using integer division on the index, e.g. `d.index // 3`. For a more general solution that works on any index, group on the range instead using a list comprehension, e.g. `[n // 3 for n in range(len(d))]`.  Then assign column `b` to the [`transformed`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) sum.

```
>>> d.assign(b=d.groupby([n // 3 for n in range(len(d))])['b'].transform(np.sum))
   a   b
0  1  36
1  2  36
2  3  36
3  4  45
4  5  45
5  6  45
6  7  54
7  8  54
8  9  54
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous solutions will solve the question; this is for a generic case, if the index is not numeric and monotonic :

The grouper, when used within the groupby, ensures the pairing for every 3 rows, regardless of the contents of the index.

```
grouper = np.repeat([0, 1, 2], len(d) // 3)

d.assign(b=d.groupby(grouper).b.transform("sum"))

    a   b
0   1   36
1   2   36
2   3   36
3   4   45
4   5   45
5   6   45
6   7   54
7   8   54
8   9   54
```